# Bash, obtain email body from a text file including the email

Tags: bash, email, unix

I have multiple files in a folder and each of them have one email message. Each message has a header in the format

```
Subject: formatting fonts 
To: XXX@XXX.COM 
From: sender 

email body
```

How can I get the body? I can get the subject , to ,from by something like "read XX"..
Since there's no tag like "Body:" I cant get the email body for now

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want everything but the first paragraph. `sed` can do this:

```
sed '1,/^$/d' file.txt
```

What it says is -- start at the beginning, (`1`) go to the first line that's blank (`^$` -- has nothing between the beginning `^` and end `$`) and delete it (`d`).

Comment: Actually, because sed doesn't do non-greedy matching, this will delete everything up to the last blank line in the email. So if the body has a blank line in it (or at the end), it'll wipe out some or all of the body. Try awk 'p;/^\s*$/{p=1}' (which will wait until it sees the first blank line, then prints lines after that.)

Comment: From the "Range Addresses" [section](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses) of the manual: *An address range matches lines starting from where the first address matches, and continues until the second address matches*.

Comment: That is to say, the regex is matched greedily, but it is evaluated on every line individually. Once a line matches (for the first time), it marks the boundary of the range. So in that sense, the matching of addresses *is* non-greedy.

Comment: This doesn't work if the email uses CR-LF line endings as is often the case. Use this instead: `sed '1,/^\r*$/d'`. Or better yet, use `formail -I ""` as suggested by Luca Gibelli's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The header and body of an email are always separated by one blank line.  You need to read (and ignore) all of the lines until you see a blank line.  The rest of the file is the body.

Comment: Per RFC 2822, I might add.

Answer (score 1):

pipe the message into:

```
| formail -I ''
```

part of the procmail package.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `pcregrep` and matches the subject, to, and from lines, then gets the inverse of that match.

```
pcregrep -M -v 'Subject.*\nTo.*\nFrom.*\n' file.txt
```